# equal width and height with LESS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I have a LESS style rule which should apply to an element with equal width and height values.
This value should be 3% of width of element's parent.
This is what I've done so far by JavaScript evaluation and a little jQuery:

```
element {
    @var: ~`Math.round(($(parent).width()*3)/100)+"px"`;
    width: @var;
    height: @var;
}
```

So my questions is:
is there any native way in LESS so I can achieve this without JavaScript evals? thanks in advance.

Comment: From your comment to my now deleted answer: `height: 3%` would be 3% of the height of the parent when you want same value in px for width and height.

Answer (score -2):

in my opinion there's no reason to use javascript at all - i'd use css directly and add a class to all the elements i want to have just 3% of their parents - like this:

```
.threepercent{
  height:3%;
  width:3%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As long as your elements are `block` level you can just percentages.  If it isn't working it's possible your elements are `inline`.

```
parent-element {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

parent-element element {
    display: block;
    width: 3%;  // will be 10px
    height: 3%; // will be 10px
}
```

or

```
@parentSize: 300px;

parent-element {
    display: block;
    width: @parentSize;
    height: @parentSize;
}

child-element {
    display: block;
    width: @parentSize* 0.03;
    height: @parentSize* 0.03;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it matters, percentages will still work with child elements based on the rendered size of the parent.  I just used fixed size for the parent to demonstrate.  See this example http://jsfiddle.net/eKJhT/.  If you view the computed CSS of the child you'll see it's 20x20 (10% of the parent's computed value).

Comment: your problem is that you assume both width and height of the parent are same values but that's not the case. imagine `element` is nested under `body` and `body` doesn't have same computed width and height.